# how to add conditions inside itemize list?

Tags: xetex, conditionals, itemize, article

List mentioned below is having three items.
There are four variables : 1] varone 2] vartwo 3] varthree and 4] sub ; which are coming from external CSV file. 
Item 2 with "Value B" will be displayed if value of variable sub is more than 4. But somehow this code does not work : can you please suggest me how to add conditions inside itemize list?

```
\begin{itemize}
\ifboolexpr{
  test {\ifdimgreater{\varone pt}{69.99pt}} or
  test {\ifdimequal{\varone pt}{69.99pt}}}
{\item \textbf{Value A: } Text for A.}{}
\ifnum\sub > 4
\ifboolexpr{
  test {\ifdimgreater{\vartwo pt}{69.99pt}} or
  test {\ifdimequal{\vartwo pt}{69.99pt}}}
{\item \textbf{Value B: } Text for B.}{}
\fi
\ifboolexpr{
  test {\ifdimgreater{\varthree pt}{69.99pt}} or
  test {\ifdimequal{\varthree pt}{69.99pt}}}
{\item \textbf{Value C: } Text for C.}{}
\end{itemize}
```

Note: I'm using article document class with xelatex.

Comment: Could you please make the example into a complete compilable document? "Somehow doesn't work” is too generic.

Comment: Perhaps this does not fit your usage, but: why not use e.g. python to generate a LaTeX file from the CSV file?

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. It distilled a little MWE and it works flawlessly.